# How to enable Mule server notifications by default?

Tags: mule

When running a Mule App from Mule Studio on the provided server, I'm able to "listen" to server notifications by default from a class implementing the interface EndpointMessageNotificationListener.

When I deploy the same code in our standalone environment (version 3.6.1) which runs in a cluster— I'm not able to retrieve the same notifications. What's needed to enable the server notifications by default?

I don't want to have to configure this in each app— but maybe we need to? Is there a configuration when starting the mule-servers to enable the server notifications by default? (which is achieved on the Mule server provided with Mule Studio?)

If we need to enable the notifications in each app. How to achieve this? I've tried (where com.company.EndpointListener is my class implementing the EndpointMessageNotificationListener interface):

```
<spring:bean name="endpointListener" class="com.company.EndpointListener"/>

<notifications>
  <notification event="ENDPOINT-MESSAGE"/> 
  <notification-listener ref="endpointListener"/>
</notifications>
```

(As described here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Server+Notifications)

But it does nothing. My class still doesn't receive any notifications in our standalone-environment. Any pointers to getting it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this turned out to be a rather obscure fix when I found out what the problem was.

A different notification listener wasn't initiated correctly, which then hindered all other notification listeners from receiving any notifications (which is a bit dangerous).

The other notification listeners problem was that it tried to read a properties-file during initialization in this way (which works when deployed to the server utilized by Mule Studio):

```
MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("MyFile.file")
```

But I needed to change it to:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("MyFile.file")
```

otherwise the listener caused an exception:

```
org.mule.work.DefaultWorkListener: Work caused exception on 'workCompleted'. Work being executed was: org.mule.context.notification.ServerNotificationManager@5a66c9cf
```

and after that, no notification listeners at all could receive any notifications.

As soon as I handled this case, all other listeners started receiving notifications without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Is a bug:
https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-7183

I have the same problem. Several days and I could not make it work :(

According :

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/mule-server-notifications#notification-interfaces

There are several notifications interfaces :  **Component Message** Notification,**Endpoint Message** Notification,Connection Notification,Custom Notification,ETC

Here some approaches to catch component and enpoint messages:

- Intercept only component messages

This solutions like me. Needs minimum effort and minimal configuration. The problem is that It can receive enpoint messages :(

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.mule.api.MuleEvent;
import org.mule.api.MuleMessage;
import org.mule.api.context.notification.MessageProcessorNotificationListener;
import org.mule.api.processor.MessageProcessor;
import org.mule.context.notification.MessageProcessorNotification;

public class ComponentMessageProcessor implements MessageProcessorNotificationListener<MessageProcessorNotification> {
private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ComponentMessageProcessor.class);

@Override
public void onNotification(MessageProcessorNotification m) {
    MuleEvent ev = m.getSource();
    MuleMessage msg = ev.getMessage();
    Object payload = msg.getPayload();
    String ref = payload != null ? payload.toString() : "null";

    MessageProcessor proc = m.getProcessor();
    log.info(String.format("\n\n\n[%s][%s][%s][%s]\n\n\n", ev.getFlowConstruct().getName(),m.getProcessorPath(), proc.getClass().getSimpleName(),ref));

  }

}
```

And in mule xml config :

```
<spring:beans>
        <spring:bean name="componentMessageProcessor" class="com.mycompany.ComponentMessageProcessor"></spring:bean>
    </spring:beans>
```

Or in spring configuration:

```
<bean name="componentMessageProcessor" class="com.mycompany.componentMessageProcessor"></bean>
```

I tried catch endpoint messages with:

```
implements EndpointMessageNotificationListener<EndpointMessageNotification>{

instead of

implements MessageProcessorNotificationListener<MessageProcessorNotification> {
```

But listener is not triggered.

source: [Mule - Intercept all flows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28469959/mule-intercept-all-flows)

- Intercept Enpoint Messages.

Is not clean and is intrusive.

```
import org.mule.api.MuleEvent;
import org.mule.api.MuleException;
import org.mule.api.processor.MessageProcessor;

public class EndpointMessageProcesor  implements MessageProcessor{

    @Override
    public MuleEvent process(MuleEvent event) throws MuleException {
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n"+event.getMessage().getPayload()+"\n\n\n\n");
        return event;
    }

}
```

And in mule config :

```
<jms:inbound-endpoint queue="queue.req" ...>
            <custom-processor class="com.mycompany.EndpointMessageProcesor"></custom-processor>
        </jms:inbound-endpoint>
```

This works in a outbound-endpoint also.

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

A little tip for visitors trying to achieve same results.
First you should implement a Java class according to what you want to be notified about as per example below:

```
package stackoverflow.mule.notifications

. . .

public class MyEndpointNotificationListener implements EndpointMessageNotificationListener<EndpointMessageNotification> {

    @Override
    public void onNotification(EndpointMessageNotification notification) {        

        // Whatever you have to do when notified goes here.
    }
}
```

Then comes your Mule configuration. First you register your notification listener as Spring bean:

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean name="MyEndpointNotificationListener" 
                 class="stackoverflow.mule.notifications.MyEndpointNotificationListener" 
                 id="MyEndpointNotificationListener" />
</spring:beans>
```

And just below it you have to register your notification as below:

```
<notifications>
    <notification event="ENDPOINT-MESSAGE"/>
    <notification-listener ref="MyEndpointNotificationListener" />
</notifications>
```

And there you go. Should work now. This has been used in Mule ESB 3.8 (CE or EE).

Cheers!